# Custom Listener of Android Button

Tags: android, android-button

I need to create Custom Listener for Android Button. The Listener should call the refresh method form another class. Please give me an idea.

Thanks

Comment: Read the API docs.  Button.setOnClickListener http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnClickListener%28android.view.View.OnClickListener%29

Answer (score 0):

You can use existing listener. Create object from that class in the listener or in any point you want and just call that method.

Comment: Ya for reply. not for development